# How to set date and month in input type month from text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three input fields:

```
<input type="month" id="incidentDate" name="incidentDate" class="incidentDate" />
<h:inputText id="incidentMonth" styleClass="incidentMonth" value="#{incidents.month}" />
<h:inputText id="incidentYear" styleClass="incidentYear" value="#{incidents.year}" />
```

i am trying to convert input type text value into date format but its not working.

I am doing this in jquery and i also want in page onload as i am getting data form backend on load

```
var newdate = $(".incidentMonth").val() + "-" + $(".incidentYear").val();
var converdate = new Date(newdate);
$("#incidentDate").val(converdate);
```

for some more info i am getting value in **"incidentYear"** 2011 and in month **incidentMonth** is 12 jsut like year and month

http://jsfiddle.net/x3j199yd/5/

Comment: We have no idea what exactly the value you are passing in `value` attribute and also we can't help much if you just say `its not working`.

Comment: edited the question .. and getting exact year and month in variable

Comment: Could you supply us with a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that, you want to set month and year in input type "month". So here is code

```
var userInput= $("#incidentMonth").val() + "-" + $("#incidentYear").val();
var dataObj= new Date(userInput);
var myNewDate=dataObj.getFullYear().toString() +'-'+ (parseInt(dataObj.getMonth())+1).toString()
myNewDate= myNewDate.split('-')[1].length<2? myNewDate.split('-')[0]+'-0'+myNewDate.split('-')[1]:myNewDate.split('-')[0]+'-'+myNewDate.split('-')[1]
document.getElementById("incidentDate").value = myNewDate;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2js0yc6/3/)